# Change the "main site" on a wordpress multisite installation

Tags: multisite

I'm trying to install the Wordpress installer so I can import a lot of data from my local development machine onto a site.

```
WordPress       This importer is not installed. Please install importers from the main site.
```

Unfortunately site 1 no longer has a proper vhost as it's been discontinued a while ago.

I've tried setting site 1 to non-public in the network admin, and changing these wp-config settings:

```
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 3);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 3);
```

So far this still tries to direct me to the defunct web address.

Any other database settings or config settings I can change to move the "main site" to a different number?